# How to send value from createContainer to global in React/Meteor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I'm implementing Kurounin Pagination.
I use the global variable and need to query document with specific field.
How can I send the variable from createContainer to global?

(Note: I want to send eventId from createContainer to const pagination)

(from the console.log(eventId); -> this show "undefined")

My code is below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import createReactClass from 'create-react-class';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Table, Alert, Button, FormGroup, FormControl, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';
import { Events } from '../../api/events';
import { Registers } from '../../api/registers';
import { TotalAmount } from '../../api/registers';
import BootstrapPaginator from 'react-bootstrap-pagination';
import NumberFormat from 'react-number-format';
import Loading from '../../components/Loading';


const pagination = new Meteor.Pagination(Registers, {
    filters: {eventid: this.eventId},
    sort: {createdAt: 1},
    perPage: 10,
    reactive: true,
    debug: true,
});
console.log(this.eventId);


class DSRegisters extends Component {       
    render() {
...........
}

DSRegisters.propTypes = {
    registers: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
    totalCount: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    evnt: PropTypes.object,
    loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};

export default createContainer(({ match }) => {
    eventId = match.params._evntid;
    const subevent = Meteor.subscribe('events');

    return {
        loading: !pagination.ready(),
        evnt: Events.findOne(eventId),
        registers: pagination.getPage(),
        totalCount: Registers.find({ eventid: eventId }).count(),
    };
}, DSRegisters);
```

Comment: Just add this.eventId to " filters: {eventid: this.eventId} " and console.log(this.eventId); when I get undefined error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve got it.
I just add “regs: pagination.filters({eventid: eventId}),” 
follow “registers: pagination.getPage(),”
then filtering is work fine.

```
export default createContainer(({ match }) => {
    eventId = match.params._evntid;
    const subevent = Meteor.subscribe('events');

    return {
        loading: !pagination.ready(),
        evnt: Events.findOne(eventId),
        registers: pagination.getPage(),
        regs: pagination.filters({eventid: eventId}),
        totalCount: Registers.find({ eventid: eventId }).count(),
    };
}, DSRegisters);
```

In alternative way remove "regs":
Then add componentDidMount()

```
...
    componentDidMount() {
        subscription.filters({ eventid: this.props.match.params._evntid });
    }
...
    export default createContainer(({ match }) => {
        eventId = match.params._evntid;
        const subevent = Meteor.subscribe('events');

        return {
            loading: !pagination.ready(),
            evnt: Events.findOne(eventId),
            registers: pagination.getPage(),
            totalCount: Registers.find({ eventid: eventId }).count(),
        };
    }, DSRegisters);
```